# Simplest model of simplest organism swimming in fluid

Tags: fluid-dynamics

(Hopefully this question isn't too elementary for this StackExchange.)

Given a micro-organism we'll define as two "cells" (which are the
atomic things in this model):

1. A "main" larger cell: `O`
2. A "tail" smaller cell: `o`

The `o` is connected by a locus which has free movement around the
circumference of the `O`. It looks like this:

```
O
o
```

Swimming action in fluid might look like this (think of a spermatozoa,
but with an even simpler tail):

```
 O
o

 O
 o

 O
  o
```

For the purpose of modeling this swimming motion in a computer
program, I'm trying to figure out the physics of it and the minimum
necessary to simulate realistic movement. Assumptions:

1. A 2D plane.
2. A certain level of friction (the fluid is e.g. water).
3. No buoyancy; the organisms are fully submerged and are at
   equilibrium with the surrounding water.
4. The body as a whole has a momentum and direction at all times for
   calculating its next position. The mass of `O` is 2 and the mass of
   `o` is 1.

It's my intuitive understanding that, for example, when the tail moves
by n°, the fluid which was surrounding the tail is displaced on both
sides:

```
Clockwise rotation


                          O
Fluid here moves away, -> o <- Fluid moves in to fill the 
but creates resistance.        gap created by the tail.
```

That resistance lets the `O` cell rotate. So in order to rotate itself
anti-clockwise, it moves the tail clockwise.

But that just lets the organism rotate left and right. Here is where
I'm stuck. How does an organism like this create momentum other than
rotation? Is there a natural movement that comes from rotation? Do we
need a third cell to extend the tail? If so, why?

Supposing that there is a natural movement coming from this action in
a fluid, what's the formula for that? Supposing `O` is at `(x1,y1)`,
and `o` is at `(x2,y2)`, `O` has radius `r1` and and `o` has `r2`, and
we do n° of rotation with mass `1` for `o` and mass `2` for `O`, at
velocity `v`. I would imagine there's something from fluid dynamics
that deals with how to calculate the whole body's new momentum and
direction?

I've been looking at this page on Bacterial motility and behavior,

http://www.rowland.harvard.edu/labs/bacteria/movies/showmovie.php?mov=tethered_strep

which states that:

> If a single flagellar filament, hook or polyhook is attached to the
>   substratum, the cell body will spin (Silverman and Simon, 1974).

[image]

So it seems that, indeed, tethering the `O` to a point would make it
spin, but that being unpinned would automatically make it move in some
direction.

For your entertainment, E coli. wiggle to move around, as you can see
in this funny video:

http://www.rowland.harvard.edu/labs/bacteria/movies/showmovie.php?mov=laser_trap

They use a laser to capture one E coli and move it around, finally
after releasing it, it wiggles away. I believe that wiggling is, in
the model defined here, a series of well-timed rotations at n loci
of m cells; so we come back to the base question.

My hope is to model organisms with arbitrary connected cells which
perform rotation actions, and for their movement in the fluid to be
realistic, if not in truth accurate by skimping on details.

Comment: You are going to have to learn some fluid mechanics in order to come up with a model that makes at least a minimal amount of physical sense. Specifically, you will have to rid yourself of naïve notions such as fluid "[moving] in to fill the gap created by the tail". There is no "gap". To get started, you could look at the review articles by [Eric Lauga](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev-fluid-122414-034606) and by [Guasto, Rusconi & Stocker](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev-fluid-120710-101156), and proceed from there.

Comment: Depending on the scale of your intended organism and your simulation goals you might also need to consider the 'noise' of molecular collisions (aka Brownian motion). Also don't expect too many, if any, answers to show on this question; too many things going on, and not clear what you are asking. I suggest you break the question down into more focused, separate questions.